# How to save graphic to bmp

Tags: c++, build, bmp, graphic

Need help with an interesting task. I need to write a C++ program that builds the graph and save a graphic file format bmp. I know how to initialize the bmp, but how to build a graph in it , I can`t think up. Necessary practical and theoretical help if there is a link to an article on the subject.

P.S. I apologize for my bad English :I

Comment: Which operating system and/or graphics library will you use?

Comment: @ScottMcP-MVP I will use standart C++ library, windows

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do graphics in Windows. The lowest level and most fundamental is to use the Win32 APIs that employ the GDI (Graphics Device Interface), which is built in to Windows. With GDI calls you can paint anything to the screen, and the same GDI calls can be used to paint on an in-memory bitmap that is off screen. To get started in this direction search the net for Win32 tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend FreeImage library (http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) it's simple and fast lib without additional problems, you can manipulate graphic files dealing with them like 2D array.
And also, they have nice PDF document about API, you don't need tutorials to use it, just read API and you will get it. Also pr0tip: DON'T PUT SPACES BEFORE SPECIAL CHARACTERS LIKE ",!?.".

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I can not use other libraries. Only standard tools

Comment: Hmm, you need to read something about BMP format. I mean reference.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the graphviz [package](http://www.graphviz.org/).

Comment: ow, you cannot use other libraries. Then graphviz is not for you.